# ubuntu server 20.04 netplan change vlan mac address

Tags: server, 20.04, mac, netplan, vlan

Is it possible to change the mac address for a vlan with netplan.io .yaml?

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
  vlans:
    vlan10:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      id: 10
      link: eno1
      macaddress: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Does not work.

**EDIT: Problem solved.** it seems it was a wrong macaddress. My fault, sorry. Now it works fine.

For other users, here the complete 01-eno1.yaml wich works.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
          route-metric: 500
  vlans:
    vlan10:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
          route-metric: 200
      id: 10
      link: eno1
      macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:10
    vlan20:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
          route-metric: 400
      id: 20
      link: eno1
      macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:20
    vlan30:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
          route-metric: 100
      id: 30
      link: eno1
      macaddress: 00:00:00:00:00:30
    vlan100:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
          route-metric: 300
      id: 100
      link: eno1
      macaddress: 00:00:00:00:01:00
    vlan200:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
          route-metric: 600
      id: 200
      link: eno1
      macaddress: 00:00:00:00:02:00
```